# Mac App Store, what DRM exists and how to authenticate purchases?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I have an app on the Mac App Store.

To meet the store requirements I had to remove my own serial code requirement at startup and then use apples purchase mechanism.

This raises some issues.

1. I have no way of knowing if a user has paid or not.
2. The /MASReciept/receipt data appears to only guarantee that the original purchase was genuine.

So whats stopping someone simply copying the .app to another mac?

I tried this and it worked.

As I am in a sandbox and can not see the actual mac how can I differentiate between the purchase mac and the mac the app is used on?

I am actually happy for the user to install on many macs that are using the same itunes account or part of family sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the receipt either locally or through the App Store.

> See the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html)

This is basically just a deterrent like most any other protection; a clever person can generally pirate an app at will, and there's not a whole lot you can honestly do. I would recommend focusing on making your app better — if it's worth buying then usually people are willing to pay for it.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that receipt validation only validates that the receipt is genuine, can I confirm that the user is the same person who purchased. I do not seem to understand how I can check the user is logged into an itunes account that relates to the purchase.

Comment: There are several ways you can validate receipts, although a common way is to verify the GUID against the receipt. When a user purchases something from the App Store the receipt contains a GUID; your app can then verify the GUID against that receipt to try and ensure that the person who owns the app is the one using it. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW14. Technically someone can't simply copy an app to another machine with a different account that it wasn't purchased for.

Comment: l'L'l, I did this very act today. I downloaded my app via the mac app store, compressed the .app folder, moved to another mac and the app ran. Besides the receipt and code signature, my app package  distributed is the same as I submitted to apple.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Another machine can be authorized for the same App Store account. Was the other machine authorized under the same name, and how did you verify the receipt was valid?

Comment: I do not know and need to rule the itunes login out. I believe the receipt is valid because it was my own purchase. I will check and report back. Thanks.